Creating a SharePoint custom view for document library - Multiple file links in same table row
My goal is to pull in a simple document library using a view where it lists a simple table view, with each "location" having its own row, and then if there exist the corresponding file type in the library ("budget", "travel", "staff"), then it will put the hyperlink to that file in the appropriate column on the row. I've created the necessary columns already, so each file has a value stored for "location", as well as for 'type'.  Below is an general idea of what I'm trying to achieve:



Location
Budget
Travel
Staff




Dallas
File link

File link


New York

File Link



Las Vegas
File link
File link
File link



I've tried some things with JSON and calculated columns with some google searching and Copilot, but I'm not getting anywhere with that so far.

I should add that I receive the below error trying to use a calculated column like such:
=IF([File Type]="Budget", [Name], "")
thinking that that would pull in the file name.
Sorry, something went wrong
One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas.
Technical Details
Learn more about the syntax for formulas.
Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
Correlation ID: 53d865a1-3002-6000-f758-b06bbf712cdb
Date and Time: 11/20/2024 12:51:41 PM

Check this out
